# Create an array based on another array with less elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have the following array with hundreds of objects

```
const images = [
  {
    "name" : "sky",
    "width" : "90",
    "height" : "150",
    "colours" : ["pink", "yellow", "red"],
    "price": "64"
  },
  {
    "name" : "old car",
    "width" : "90",
    "height" : "150",
    "colours" : ["dark purple", "sand", "light green"],
    "price": "35"
  },
  {
    "name" : "landscape",
    "width" : "90",
    "height" : "150",
    "colours" : ["dark blue", "violet"],
    "price": "85"
  },
  {
    "name" : "kitchen",
    "width" : "90",
    "height" : "150",
    "colours" : ["red", "green"],
    "price": "38"
  },
...
]
```

I want to create a new array that has only 10 objects and only some key/value pairs (name, colours, price). The 10 objects can be extracted by using another array of numbers to be used as index.

Here is an example of array containing the indices:

```
randomNum = [4,24,39,82,92,27,123,22,84,65]
```

The new array - expected result - should look like something similar to this

```
data = [
  {
      name: "landscape",
      colour: ["dark blue", "violet"],
      price: "85"
  },
  {
      name: "kitchen",
      colour: ["red", "green"],
      price: "38"
  },
  ...
]
```

I'm trying to iterate

```
const finalList = []; //new array
let quizItem;

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
   quizItem= images[randomNum[i]];
   finalList.push({name: quizItem.name, colour: quizItem.colour, price: quizItem.price);  
}
```

I get an error saying... `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'quizItem.name')`

If instead I just use `quizList.push(quizItem);`  it works fine and creates a new array with just the 10 records but with all the same object's items (key/value pairs) as the original array.

Comment: Fix this please  finalList.push({...); to  finalList.push({...});

Comment: that's not the problem, it was just a type in this post.

Comment: `colour` would not be a property of `quizItem` but `colours` would.

Comment: Is the error you're getting reproducible? If so, please provide a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing here is when you are accessing `randomNum[i]`, the values you are getting with `randomNum[i]` are probably out of bounds of the `images` list. Hence you're attempting to access something that is not there or simply `undefined`. As a solution, you can generate a random list safely as shown below and then use that to print your items.

```
    const images = [
    {
        "name": "sky",
        "width": "90",
        "height": "150",
        "colours": ["pink", "yellow", "red"],
        "price": "64"
    },
    {
        "name": "old car",
        "width": "90",
        "height": "150",
        "colours": ["dark purple", "sand", "light green"],
        "price": "35"
    },
    {
        "name": "landscape",
        "width": "90",
        "height": "150",
        "colours": ["dark blue", "violet"],
        "price": "85"
    },
    {
        "name": "kitchen",
        "width": "90",
        "height": "150",
        "colours": ["red", "green"],
        "price": "38"
    }
];

    generateRandomNumbersList = (size, maxValue) => {
    let randomNums = [];
    let currentNum;

    while (randomNums.length < size) {
        currentNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxValue);
        if (currentNum < maxValue) {
            randomNums.push(currentNum);
        }
    }
    return randomNums;
}

    let randomNums = generateRandomNumbersList(10, images.length);

    const finalList = []; //new array
    let quizItem;

    for (let count = 0; count < 10; count++) {
    quizItem = images[randomNums[count]];
    finalList.push({ name: quizItem.name, colour: quizItem.colours, price: quizItem.price });
}

    console.log(finalList);
```

Comment: That's not the problem as I'm already checking the max value. In fact, as a test I have replaced the random processing with a dummy array `const randomNums = [3,45,34,23,28,83,54,67,87,11];` and still getting undefined

Comment: Try this:

`console.log(images[randomNums[i]])`

If it still shows `undefined`, then print the index to make sure again.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine with the correction pointed out in the comments. **Also, you do not have a `colour` property in the objects; but you have `colours`; correct that too.** You can also use `.map()` as follows:

```
const finalList = randomNum.map(n => images[n])
.map(({name, colours, price}) => ({name, colours, price});
```

Comment: Still giving me an empty array as result. I think the problem may be around the format of the array. It I push the entire object it doesn't cause any problems and as a result I get a full new array with just those 10 objects but with all the elements inside. Btw, both functions (yours and mine) work the same. The format of the array in the console is a bit strange `images: Array [ Object { "name" ...}, Object {...},...]`

Comment: In that case could you run `console.log( JSON.stringify(images[0]) )` to get the correct structure of the objects.

Comment: It is working now but I had to iterative once again on a separate function. So now I'm doing `finalList.push(quizItem)` and save it somewhere. Then iterate through the new variable and can now point to the individual objects without any issue. It seems some sort of runtime issue